# Retrieve sonarqube rules by category

Tags: sonarqube

How can I get a list (via webservice or sql query) of all the sonar rules with his category (Maintainability, Efficiency, Reliability...etc)

Using xxxxx/api/rules?language=java&plugin=pmd,findbugs  :

```
<rule>
<title>Unnecessary Local Before Return</title>
<key>pmd:UnnecessaryLocalBeforeReturn</key>          
<config_key>rulesets/design.xml/UnnecessaryLocalBeforeReturn</config_key> 
<plugin>pmd</plugin>    
<description>Avoid unnecessarily creating local variables</description> 
<priority>MAJOR</priority>
</rule>
```

Where is the category shown in the Technical Debt dashboard??

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, thanks!!!

Meanwhile, if anyone is interested, I´m trying to do that with sql scripting...

```
CREATE VIEW lvl3 AS
select c.id, c.rule_id, c.characteristic_order, r.name, r.plugin_rule_key, r.plugin_name, r.language, ce.parent_id
from characteristics c
inner join rules r on c.rule_id=r.id
inner join characteristic_edges ce on c.id=ce.child_id
order by c.rule_id

CREATE VIEW lvl2 AS
select c.id, c.kee, c.name, c.depth, c.characteristic_order, ce.parent_id 
from characteristics c
inner join characteristic_edges ce on c.id=ce.child_id
where depth=2 order by id

CREATE VIEW lvl1 AS
select id, kee, name, depth, characteristic_order 
from characteristics 
where depth=1 order by id

select l3.rule_id as "IdRule", l3.plugin_rule_key as "Name", l3.name as "Descrition", l3.plugin_name "Plugin", l3.language as "Language", l1.name as "Category"
from lvl1 l1
inner join lvl2 l2 on l3.parent_id=l2.id
inner join lvl3 l3 on l2.parent_id=l1.id
order by l3.rule_id
```

Thats works fine for me now...... waiting for web service :)

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

As of SonarQube 4.1 (January 2014), this is not possible yet.

I have created a ticket for this improvement: [SONAR-5008](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-5008)